# Setup SD Card so it only runs on a single Windows 8 PC

Tags: windows-8, sd-card, disk-encryption

A few of our staff are running Windows 8 laptops with only 100gig solid state drives. Recently some of them have been running out of drive space.

The main user of drive space is the shared Google Drive files so I want to setup Google Drive on a 128gig SD Card which permanently stays in the laptops SD Card slot.

However for the sake of security I want to make sure that if the SD Card was removed it can't be read by any other machine.

Bitlocker almost does this but when the computer is restarted Bitlocker requires a password for the SD Card to become accessible. This isn't user friendly enough for the staff and I was wonder what the alternatives are.

Ideally we'd like to have the SD Card show up as a drive that can be read/ accessed by Google Drive - but if the SD Card is removed from the host computer it is unreadable.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Any method that does exist would require unlocking the drive before it could be used.  Bitlocker is far the safest option.  Besides you can automatically configure Bitlocker to automatically unmount the drive for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the card to be unreadable, you can do this by setting the NTFS permissions. But if you are looking for some kind of security, you'll need to activate the sd card by a password on each startup.